# How can I fix the runtime error on an input file?

Tags: input, output

I am trying to complete an assignment based on using `input` and `output.txt` files. My program compiles just fine but when I run it I am getting a run error. It prompts me to enter my input file as it should, I enter it and the program fails with below exception-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.java.healthMgmt.HealthMgmt.main(HealthMgmt.java:33)
```

the error occurs on this line

```
File f = new File(path.getFile());
```

Comment: Where does `path` get initialized? Also, use `new File(path)` instead

Comment: Please post your complete code and stacktrace as well. The path object might be null.